# ios CALayer delegate displayLayer not called

Tags: ios

ios CALayer delegate displayLayer not called

From: http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        MyLayer* _myLayer = [MyLayer layerWithImage:img sampleSize:fSize];
        _myLayer.delegate = self;

        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"imageIndex"];
        anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
        anim.duration = 2f;
        anim.repeatCount = 1;
        [richter addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:_myLayer];

    }
    return self;
}

// CALayer delegate needs this method for variable sample size to work
- (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer{
}
```

displayLayer is never called?

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: Here is some tutorial on CALayer display. Check if you can find something interesting there regarding this. http://club15cc.com/code/ios/understanding-the-ios-layer-drawing-display-hierarchy-a-detailed-look-behind-the-scenes

Comment: Thanks, I needed the + (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key; to return on the right key.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

Remember to set the

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"indexKey"];
```

To be the same as:

```
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

On the CALayer you are subClassing